# How to give size to psbarcode

Tags: pst-barcode

I'm using `pst-barcode` to generate rectangular datamatrix. Although I have problem with the fact "that the barcode is printed in a TEX box of zero dimension".

The manual suggest using `fbox` and `pspicture` environment, but it require to know the both sizes of the code apriori. Specyfying only `width` results in deformed code.